# Unable to capture record IDs for Bulk Updating Fields for non-admin users in Django Front End

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to bulk update fields for a list of records, similar to an Admin Actions type drop down list , for non-admin users in the front end.

The process a user follows -

Step 1. Come to the candidates.html page
Step 2.  Select the candidate to whose field is to be updated by selecting the check box of the respective candidate in the candidates.html page which has the table of the candidates and the first column as the check box for selection.
Step 3. Click on the mass_update_candidates button to be directed to the mass_update_candidates.html to update the fields with the new value.

Step 1 & 2 function correctly, when clicking on the mass_update_candidates button it redirects to the page, however, On clicking Update Button, it is not capturing the selected IDs

Please advise.

Below are the forms.py, views.py and the different html templates.

I do not have any coding experience. I'm trying to learn. This is a pet project I've created to learn.

Any help is most appreciated. If you know of a better method to achieve this please do let me know, I'm more than willing to try new ideas.

Thank You!

---

Browser Console Message:

JavaScript is working!
(index):253 Selected Field: gender
(index):299 Selected Field: gender
(index):302 New Value: Male
(index):305 Selected Candidate IDs:

Views.py

```
# Function to Bulk Update Candidate Fields in the Candidates List Page
def mass_update_candidates(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MassUpdateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get the selected fields and the new value from the form
            field_name = form.cleaned_data['fields']
            new_value = form.cleaned_data['new_value']

            # Get the list of selected candidates' IDs
            selected_candidate_ids = request.POST.getlist('selected_candidate_ids')

            # Update the selected field with the new value for the selected candidates
            if field_name == 'gender':
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(gender=new_value)
            elif field_name == 'communication_skills':
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(communication_skills=new_value)
            elif field_name == 'nationality':
                nationality = form.cleaned_data['nationality']
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(nationality=nationality)
            elif field_name == 'industry':
                industry = form.cleaned_data['industry']
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(industry=industry)
            elif field_name == 'highest_qualification':
                highest_qualification = form.cleaned_data['highest_qualification']
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(highest_qualification=highest_qualification)
            elif field_name == 'city':
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(city=new_value)
            elif field_name == 'country':
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(country=new_value)
            elif field_name == 'temp_id':
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(temp_id=new_value)
            elif field_name == 'created_on':
                new_datetime = datetime.strptime(new_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(created_on=new_datetime)
            elif field_name == 'created_by':
                created_by = form.cleaned_data['created_by']
                Candidate.objects.filter(id__in=selected_candidate_ids).update(created_by=created_by)

            return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'message': 'Candidates updated successfully.'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'error': 'Invalid form data.'})

    else:
        form = MassUpdateForm()
        return render(request, 'candidates/mass_update_candidates.html', {'form': form})


# Function to fetch field options based on the selected field
def get_field_options(request):
    field_name = request.GET.get('field_name')

    options = []

    if field_name == 'gender':
        options = [
            {'value': gender[0], 'label': gender[1]} for gender in Gender.choices
        ]
    elif field_name == 'communication_skills':
        options = [
            {'value': skill[0], 'label': skill[1]} for skill in Communication_Skills.choices
        ]
    elif field_name == 'nationality':
        options = [
            {'value': nationality.id, 'label': nationality.nationality} for nationality in Nationality.objects.all()
        ]
    elif field_name == 'industry':
        options = [
            {'value': industry.id, 'label': industry.industry_name} for industry in Industry.objects.all()
        ]
    elif field_name == 'highest_qualification':
        options = [
            {'value': qualification.id, 'label': str(qualification)} for qualification in Highest_Qualification.objects.all()
        ]
    elif field_name == 'created_by':
        options = [
            {'value': user.id, 'label': user.username} for user in User.objects.all()
        ]

    return JsonResponse({'options': options})
```

candidates.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<!-- Page Content-->
{% block content %}
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/candidates/candidates_list_style.css">
<div class="input-group mb-3 mt-5" style="margin-left: 7%;">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <a href="{% url 'candidates:add_a_candidate' %}" class="btn btn-primary">
            Add a Candidate
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Add the link to the mass update view -->
<div class="input-group-append">
    <a href="{% url 'candidates:mass_update_candidates' %}" class="btn btn-success">
        Mass Update Candidates
    </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="responsive-table">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="list_table" style="text-align: center;font-size: 14px;">
            <thead style="background-color: #272b30; color: #fff;">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all"><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckboxSelectAll"></th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">ID</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">CIOL</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Candidate Name</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Company</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Job Title</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Mobile Phone</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Email</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Linkedin URL</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Industry</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">City</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Country</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Nationality</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Age</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Communication Skills</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Total Experience</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Temp Id</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Source</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Current Salary</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Expected Salary</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Candidate Called By</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Candidate Called On</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Candidate Disposition</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Created On</th>
                    <th style="width:auto;text-align:center" class="all">Created By</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for candidate in candidates %}
            <tr style="background-color: #272b30; color:white">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="select_row" data-id="{{ candidate.id }}"></td>
                <td>{{ candidate.id }}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" {% if not candidate.ciol %}disabled{% endif %} {% if candidate.ciol %}checked{% endif %}></td>
                <td><a style="text-decoration:none" href="candidates/{{ candidate.slug }}"><font color="white">{{ candidate.candidate_name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ candidate.company }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.job_title }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.mobile_phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.email }}</td>
                <td><a style="text-decoration:none" href="{{ candidate.linkedin_url }}" target="_blank"><font color="white">{{ candidate.linkedin_url }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ candidate.industry }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.city }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.country }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.nationality }}</td>
                <td>{{ simplify.age }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.communication_skills }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.total_experience|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.temp_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.source|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.current_salary|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.expected_salary|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.candidate_called_by|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.candidate_called_on|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.candidate_disposition|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.created_on }}</td>
                <td>{{ candidate.created_by }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Datatables Script -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#list_table thead tr')
            .clone(true)
            .addClass('filters')
            .appendTo('#list_table thead');

        var table = $('#list_table').DataTable({
            orderCellsTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            responsive: true,
            scrollX: true,
            colReorder: true,
            dom: 'QBlfrtip',
            buttons: ['createState', 'savedStates'],
            initComplete: function () {
                var api = this.api();

                // For each column
                api.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
                    // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                    var cell = $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index());
                    var title = $(cell).text();
                    $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');

                    // On every keypress in this input
                    $(
                        'input',
                        $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                    )
                        .off('keyup change')
                        .on('change', function (e) {
                            // Get the search value
                            $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                            var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();

                            var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                            // Search the column for that value
                            api
                                .column(colIdx)
                                .search(
                                    this.value != ''
                                        ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                        : '',
                                    this.value != '',
                                    this.value == ''
                                )
                                .draw();
                        })
                        .on('keyup', function (e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();

                            $(this).trigger('change');
                            $(this)
                                .focus()[0]
                                .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                        });
                });
                

                // Add Select All checkbox at the top
                $('#list_table thead tr.filters').prepend('<th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckbox"></th>');

                // Handle Select All checkbox behavior for the first column
                $('#selectAllCheckboxSelectAll').change(function () {
                    var checked = this.checked;
                    $('#list_table tbody input.select_row').prop('checked', checked);
                });

                // Handle Select All checkbox behavior
                $('#selectAllCheckbox').change(function () {
                    var checked = this.checked;
                    $('#list_table tbody input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', checked);
                });

                // Handle Select All checkbox behavior for individual rows
                $('#list_table tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
                    if (!this.checked) {
                        $('#selectAllCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
                    } else {
                        var allChecked = $('#list_table tbody input[type="checkbox"]').length === $('#list_table tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
                        $('#selectAllCheckbox').prop('checked', allChecked);
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    // Function to handle the mass update button click event
    document.getElementById("massUpdateButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        const selectedCandidateIds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="selected_candidate_ids"]:checked'))
            .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

        if (selectedCandidateIds.length === 0) {
            alert("Please select candidates to update.");
        } else {
            // Redirect to mass update page with selected candidate IDs
            window.location.href = `{% url 'candidates:mass_update_candidates' %}?selected_candidate_ids=${selectedCandidateIds.join(",")}`;
        }
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

mass_update_candidates.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h3>Mass Update Candidates</h3>
    <form id="massUpdateForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Select Field to Update:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="fields" name="fields">
                        <option value="">---------</option>
                        <option value="gender">Gender</option>
                        <option value="communication_skills">Communication Skills</option>
                        <option value="nationality">Nationality</option>
                        <option value="industry">Industry</option>
                        <option value="highest_qualification">Highest Qualification</option>
                        <option value="city">City</option>
                        <option value="country">Country</option>
                        <option value="temp_id">Temp ID</option>
                        <option value="created_on">Created On</option>
                        <option value="created_by">Created By</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>New Value:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="new_value" name="new_value">
                        <!-- Options for "New Value" will be loaded dynamically using JavaScript -->
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="button" id="updateButton" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    // Function to handle the mass update process using JavaScript and jQuery
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fields").on("change", function () {
            const selectedField = $(this).val();
            if (selectedField) {
                // Load options for "New Value" dropdown based on the selected field
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'candidates:get_field_options' %}",
                    method: "GET",
                    data: {
                        field_name: selectedField,
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Clear existing options
                        $("#new_value").empty();

                        // Populate options based on the data received from the server
                        for (const option of data.options) {
                            $("#new_value").append(
                                `<option value="${option.value}">${option.label}</option>`
                            );
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("An error occurred while loading options.");
                        console.error(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $("#updateButton").on("click", function () {
            const selectedField = $("#fields").val();
            const newValue = $("#new_value").val();
            const selectedCandidateIds = [];
            $("input[name='selected_candidate_ids']:checked").each(function () {
                selectedCandidateIds.push($(this).val());
            });

            if (selectedField && newValue && selectedCandidateIds.length > 0) {
                const formData = {
                    fields: selectedField,
                    new_value: newValue,
                    selected_candidate_ids: selectedCandidateIds,
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'candidates:mass_update_candidates' %}",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    headers: {
                        "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            alert(data.message);
                            window.location.reload(); // Reload the page after successful update
                        } else {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("An error occurred while processing the request.");
                        console.error(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Please select fields, provide a new value, and select candidates to update.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

---

I'm trying to bulk update fields for a list of records, similar to an Admin Actions type drop down list , for non-admin users in the front end.

The process a user follows -

Step 1. Come to the candidates.html page
Step 2.  Select the candidate to whose field is to be updated by selecting the check box of the respective candidate in the candidates.html page which has the table of the candidates and the first column as the check box for selection.
Step 3. Click on the mass_update_candidates button to be directed to the mass_update_candidates.html to update the fields with the new value.

Step 1 & 2 function correctly, when clicking on the mass_update_candidates button it redirects to the page, however, On clicking Update Button, it is not capturing the selected IDs